# Azure active directory authentication Function App

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I am doing azure active directory authentication for function app by following below URL
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/secure-azure-function-with-azure-ad/

But when i hitting  my url through function app
It is giving unauthorized do i need to do anything else

please find the below screen shots.

[image]

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use the access token to access your Azure function API directly if your azure function authentication level is anonymous or function key is also required. The detailed steps are as below.

1. Configure Azure AD for Azure Function. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#auth.
2. Get Access token

I get an access token from AAD using clientID and clientSecret using the following code:

```
METHOD: POST

Url : https://login.microsoftonline.com/your directory ID/oauth2/token 

HEADERS:  Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

BODY: grant_type+=client_credentials&resource+=”your Function url”&client_id+++++=”the application that your register  id”&client_secret+=”the key you create”
```

Please note that according to the Azure Resources portal (https://resources.azure.com/), the default allowedAudiences is

```
https://{functionAppName}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
```

So I added the `https://{functionAppName}.azurewebsites.net/` as allowed audiences.

[image]

Then I can use the access token directly. I tested it with Postman:

[image]

Please note that if your azure function authentication level is not anonymous, you need to add the function key

Comment: I added the url to allowed audience and used postman; I'm still getting the message "You do not have permission to view this directory or page". Is it possible that I'm getting the wrong access_token from AAD?

Comment: Hello, I was able to resolve the problem. The issue was with the AAD token generated. Passing App ID instead of "https://<AzureFunctionAppName>.azurewebsites.net/" in context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://<AzureFunctionAppName>.azurewebsites.net/", cc).Result

Comment: small doubt in the above u mentioned URL https://login.microsoftonline.com/your directory ID/oauth2/token 
"Your directory ID" is necessary

Comment: The directory ID is necessary. If you do not know your directory ID, you can use "common". for more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow.

Comment: Hi i know tenant id but we dont wan't to use that one to generate token is there any alternative? u mentioned in above statement "Common"  may i know what is that?
i have followed u mentioned URL In the above statement but i did not get anything

Comment: @ Jim i have tried with common but it throw's an error also the link does not talk about it. can u help with an example?

Comment: please find the below error One or more errors occurred. (AADSTS50059: No tenant-identifying information found in either the request or implied by any provided credentials. Trace ID: 24cd7f6c-69e6-452e-bf11-ae6f1fa12d00 Correlation ID: 9d5be18c-4970-4a9c-8af7-c0dda18b2e23 Timestamp: 2019-03-07 13:02:24Z)

Comment: According to my test, you need to update your identifierUris in the Manifest file. And specify resource url as identifierUris in your code.