# Accessing oAuth2 protected Azure Function from Daemon Application

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, daemon

I have several Azure Functions that I would like to apply authentication using Azure AD on. I have done that successfully when it comes to user impersonated authentication. But unfortunately, I'm not able to get the same working from daemon applications trying to access the Azure Functions.

My Daemon applications are registered in Azure AD, and exposing App scopes. Basically, I have other APIs that are built as App Services getting authenticated to successfully from daemon applications. I applied the same configurations for Azure functions, but they are not working.

My question is, has anybody managed to authenticate daemon apps to Azure Functions using Azure AD? and if so, I appreciate if they can guide me to any documentation on how to achieve that

Thank you

Comment: Could you tell me how you configure Azure AD for azure function?

Comment: Have you referred to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55022474/azure-active-directory-authentication-function-app/55033947#55033947?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... Actually, it only worked after matching the Token Audience with the Application ID URI. Initially I used the application client ID as the token audience, but that didn't work

Comment: Since your issue has been resolved, could you please post your answer? It can help more people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using the exact value of my application ID URI which was in the format api://{application-id} in the Token Audiences in the function's authentication configuration